# <nav> element is overflowing the <header>

Tags: html, css, nav

The`<nav>` element is not rendered inside the `<header>` element even though it is nested inside.

I tried adding the `over-flow:hidden` property to the `<header>` element, using the `index-head` class. I also tried adding both `position:relative` and `position:absolute`.

```css
 *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  ul{
      list-style: none;
  }
  a{
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .index-head{
      height: 90px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .logo{
      width: 50px;
      float: left;
      margin: 20px;
      margin-right: 0;
  }
  .brand-name{
      color: #ffc107;
      line-height: 90px;
      font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  }
  .index-head nav{
      float: right;
      margin-top: 0;
      width: 50%;
  }
  .index-head nav ul li{
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 25px;
      padding-left: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="index-head">
        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
        <h1 class="brand-name">Eeat</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get the `<nav>` inside the `<header>` is to set the `<h1.brand-name>` element to `display:inline-block`. By default browser agents set `<hX>` tags to `display:block`, which spans those elements 100% of the available space and in this case is was pushing your `<nav>` down below it. Since the `<header>` has a fixed height this forced the `<nav>` outside.

I also added...

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
```

To `<header.index-head>` to space the child elements evenly vertically and horizontally.

I then added `flex-grow: 1;` to the `<nav>` element, which makes sure it takes 'priority' when flex-box determines its width relative to its siblings.

*Learn more about [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)*

```css
 *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  ul{
      list-style: none;
  }
  a{
      text-decoration: none;
  }
  .index-head{
      height: 90px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .logo{
      width: 50px;
      float: left;
      margin: 20px;
      margin-right: 0;
  }
  .brand-name{
      color: #ffc107;
      line-height: 90px;
      font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .index-head nav{
      float: right;
      margin-top: 0;
      width: 50%;
      flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .index-head nav ul li{
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 25px;
      padding-left: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="index-head">
        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
        <h1 class="brand-name">Eeat</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you added a "h1" tag inside the header, which by default has

```
display: block
```

property that stretches the element to the entire width of the "header" element.

to solve this problem, you must add a css rule to the "h1" element

```
display: inline-block;
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nzf1egcr/1/

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to usurp you there! I must have started before you posted. Only leaving my answer because there's a few other things that need fixing.